# How can I handle with special characters or scape them on spark version 3.3.0?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Previously I was using spark version 3.2.1 to read data from SAP database by JDBC connector, I had no issues to perform the following steps:

```
df_1 = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", "URL_LINK") \
.option("dbtable", 'DATABASE."/ABC/TABLE"') \
.option("user", "USER_HERE") \
.option("password", "PW_HERE") \
.option("driver", "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver") \
.load()

display(df_1)

df_2 = df_1.filter("`/ABC/COLUMN` = 'ID_HERE'")

display(df_2)
```

This code above runs as it should, returning expected rows.

Since I updated my spark version to 3.3.0, because I need to have the new trigger 'availableNow' (trigger from streaming process), this process above started to fail, does not run at all.

Please follow the error message bellow.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<command-963568451378752> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 df_2 = df_1.filter("`/ABC/COLUMN` = 'ID_HERE'")
      2 
----> 3 display(df_2)

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/display.py in display(self, 
input, *args, **kwargs)
     81                     raise Exception('Triggers can only be 
set for streaming queries.')
     82 
---> 83                 self.add_custom_display_data("table", 
input._jdf)
     84 
     85         elif isinstance(input, list):

/databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/display.py in 
add_custom_display_data(self, data_type, data)
     34     def add_custom_display_data(self, data_type, data):
     35         custom_display_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
---> 36         return_code = 
self.entry_point.addCustomDisplayData(custom_display_key, 
data_type, data)
     37         ip_display({
     38             "application/vnd.databricks.v1+display": 
custom_display_key,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5- 
src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = 
self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, 
self.name)
   1323 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    200                 # Hide where the exception came from that 
shows a non-Pythonic
    201                 # JVM exception message.
--> 202                 raise converted from None
    203             else:
    204                 raise

ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '/': extra input 
'/'(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
/ABC/COLUMN
^^^
```

I've already tried to format in so many different ways, following the instructions on: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html . I've already tried to use function string by previously formatting the string, also tried raw string, but nothing seems to work as supposed.

Another important information, I've tried to create a dummy code for you to be able to replicate the issue, but when I create those tables with slashes '/ABC/TABLE' containing  columns with slashes '/ABC/COLUMN' directly on pyspark, instead of using JDBC connector, it actually works, I was able to filter.

As described above, I am expecting to perform the filter, no matter the spark version.

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.